# Get Real Free Usable Space

Tags: c++, ubuntu, diskspace

I've got an issue with a program that should send me back the free disk space usable by any user.

My goal is to get all the free disk space of every partitions of my hard drive that is usable by anyone who doesn't have sudo rights.

So I tryed this :

```
int main() {
    struct statvfs diskData;
    statvfs("/", &diskData);
    unsigned long long available = (diskData.f_favail + diskData.f_bavail) * diskData.f_frsize) / (1024 * 1024)
    std::cout << "Free Space : " << available << std::endl;
}
```

This gives me a total of 2810 ...

However, when I output `df -h`, I can read that the available space is `25G` for `sda3` and `30G` for `sda1`

This seems completely inaccurate.

I've been running on the posts on Stackoverflow, mixing solutions I saw, but none is satisfactory. How can I get a correct value in Megabytes of my available free space ?

EDIT : Full `statvfs` and `df /` output

`statvfs` :

```
Block Size            : 4 096
Fragment Size         : 4 096
Blocks                : 9 612 197
Free Blocks           : 7 009 166
Non Root Free Blocks  : 6 520 885
Inodes                : 2 444 624
Free Inodes Space     : 2 137 054
Non Root Free Inodes  : 2 137 054
File System ID        : 4 224 884 198
Mount Flags           : 4 096
Max Filename Length   : 255
```

`df /` :

```
Filesystem     1K-Blocks      Used           Available      Use%     Mounted on
/dev/sda3      38 448 788     10 412 112     26 083 556     29%      /
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the right value to use is the fragment size, not the block size (i.e. f_frsize)

Have you tried with

```
diskData.f_bavail * diskData.f_frsize
```

instead ?

Comment: Yes I thought it was better ! But the Fragment Size and the Block Size is the same value on my system. I got the same result.

Comment: Could you then update the post with the whole output of `statvfs` and `df /` (without -h) ? It would help a lot.

Comment: 6 520 885 * 4096 / 1024 makes 26 083 540, which is quite close to the output of df (26 083 556). Dividing the value by 1024*1024 should give you the expected output.

Comment: I guess you're using 32 bit signed integers, which can represent at most 2^31-1 (about 2 147 483 647). 6 520 886 * 4096 equals 26 709 549 056, which is greater. You should use at least a 64 bit integer or, if you approximate values are enough, a floating point type.

Comment: You have to do the conversion _before_ doing the multiplication. For example `float f_bavail = diskData.f_bavail; float f_frsize = diskData.f_frsize;     float available = f_bavail * f_frsize / (1024 * 1024);`

Answer (score 4):

This seems like a more accurate measure of the free disk space:

```
unsigned long long available = (diskData.f_bavail * diskData.f_bsize) / (1024 * 1024);
```

It matches the output from `df` quite closely on my system (`df` shows the sizes in gigs, and probably rounds them).

If you want the output in gigs like `df` you could use this:

```
#include <sys/statvfs.h>
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long rounddiv(unsigned long num, unsigned long divisor) {
    return (num + (divisor/2)) / divisor;
}

int main() {
    struct statvfs diskData;
    statvfs("/home", &diskData);
    unsigned long available = diskData.f_bavail * diskData.f_bsize;
    printf("Free Space : %luG\n", rounddiv(available, 1024*1024*1024));
    return 0;
}
```

The output from this on my system:
`Free Space : 31G`

And if I run `df -h /home`:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
                      181G  141G   31G  83% /home
```

Comment: Hum, you must be right, however I now get the result `1992` with what you proposed me. `f_bavail` returns `510 003` and `f_bsize` returns `4096`. Is `available` in Gigs of Megs ? Because neither seem accurate again ... Am I missing something ?

Comment: Thanks for the new answer. I think your code must be right, but I must have another problem then, because I output `1G` when I use `/` and `df -h /` tells me that on  `/dev/sda3` (only thing mounted on `/`) I got `25G` available ...